# Cannot postMessage(CanvasRenderingContext2D)

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker, postmessage

As part of a custom library, I isolated the following snippet, run from a main browser's thread, which produces the error:
`DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.`

The snippet's goal is to provide `worker` with an instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 1;
canvas.height = 1;

worker.postMessage(canvas.getContext("2d"));
```

Is `postMessage` failure due to a specific attribute of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` which cannot be "cloned"? What workarounds may I consider?

Answer (score 1):

> Is postMessage failure due to a specific attribute of CanvasRenderingContext2D which cannot be "cloned"?

I would guess that those would be all of the functions.

> [Things that don't work with structured clones:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm)
>
> `Error` and `Function` objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a `DATA_CLONE_ERR` exception.

This sounds like what your facing.

You can't send the whole `<canvas>` element either, because

> Attempting to clone DOM nodes will likewise throw a `DATA_CLONE_ERR` exception.

I have no idea if this will work, but what you probably need is just the context from the properties (fillStyle, lineHeight, etc). You could just extract those (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(canvas.getContext("2d")))`) and try sending those. :/

Answer (score 0):

**DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': CanvasRenderingContext2D object could not be cloned.**

This error occurred in web worker worker.onmessage(()=>{}) in my case when I was trying to copy a undefined value(data.data).

```
let ele = {};
worker.onmessage = (data) => {
  ele.data == data.data
}
```